# How can I modify a dropdown item in bootstrap-vue to open a modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

How can i modify the below drop down to include a modal in bootstrap vue:

I want some of my dropdown items to open a modal, and some to go to be href. I am ok with the href. But how do i go about making some of these drop down items open a modal?

```html
<template>
  <b-dropdown-item v-bind="$props" :href="to ? undefined : href || '#'">
    <feather-icon size="1x" :icon="icon"/>
      {{name}}
  </b-dropdown-item>
</template>
<script>
import FeatherIcon from '@/components/FeatherIcon';
export default {
  name: 'feather-dd-item',
  props: ['icon', 'name', 'href', 'to'],
  components: { FeatherIcon }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're spreading your component's `$props` onto a `<b-dropdown-item>`.

You can't really add `v-b-modal` to your components' props because that would mean setting `v-b-modal` on the wrapper, which would make the wrapper open the modal, instead of the dropdown item. So we need a substitute prop to transport the `id` of the modal. I suggest `modalTarget`.
Inside the markup, just map `modalTarget` (containing the modal id) to `v-b-modal` directive:
`<b-dropdown-item v-b-modal='modalTarget' />`.

Obviously, you have to add `modalTarget` to the `props` array. Final markup should look like this:

```html
<template>
  <b-dropdown-item v-b-modal="modalTarget"
                   v-bind="$props"
                   :href="to ? undefined : href || '#'">
    <feather-icon size="1x" :icon="icon"/>
    {{name}}
  </b-dropdown-item>
</template>
<script>
import FeatherIcon from '@/components/FeatherIcon';
export default {
  name: 'feather-dd-item',
  props: ['icon', 'name', 'href', 'to', 'modalTarget'],
  components: { FeatherIcon }
};
</script>
```

Should work. Now you can use

```
<feather-dd-item modalTarget="my-modal" />
```

, which will open the modal with `id="my-modal"`, if it finds one.